# Java. Reference to method without parameters

Tags: java, java-8

I have one problem in understanding of Java 8 associated with reference to methods as a parameter to static methods. There is my code where I can't find how to send a reference to a method which doesn't have any parameters and must be a method for an object of the definite class.

So, I want that the method which I send to static function may be used for the object in the static method.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface FuncForPath<T> {
    T func(T path);
}

class MethodsForFolder {

    public static void printFilesInFolder(Path path, FuncForPath<Path> funcPath) {
        Stream<Path> paths = null;
        try {
            paths = Files.list(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "The problems have been appeared during reading folder: " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Files list in folder:" + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        paths.forEach(p -> funcPath.func(p).toString()); // I don't know to how to write this code to perform
    }
}

public class TestRefToIntance {

    public static String testWindowsFloder = "C://Logs";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path path = Paths.get(testWindowsFloder);
        // I want that this 2 methods are performed depending on transfered methods
        // reference
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::toAbsolutePath);
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::getFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code not work? What errors does it give you? Does it work, but yields unexpected results? Please specify.

Comment: Sorry I have posted before the code with a static method from another class. I have edited the code it works now like a previous version.

I see a message "Files list in folder:C:\Logs".

Answer (score 1):

Try `Function<Path, Path>` instead of `FuncForPath`. This will require a method taking a `Path` parameter and returning a `Path`. Note that instance methods always have an "invisible" `this` parameter, hence `Path::getFileName` matches that signature.

You'd then call it like this: `paths.forEach( p -> funcPath.apply( p ).toString() );` (although you're not doing anything with the returned string, so you probably want to call `paths.map( f ).map( Path::toString ).collect( someCollector );` instead.

Comment: ...and you can do `paths.map(funcPath).map(Path::toString)` so it transforms from your path to the path your function returns, then into the string representation. Also note you might want to actually print them by `.forEach(System.out::println)` or something.

Comment: @daniu yes, just added the usage part :)

Comment: Soory, It was my bad. I wanted to print the list of files in the console.

Comment: Another possibility is `.map(f.andThen(Path::toString)).collect(...)`

Answer (score 0):

How I understand I have resolved this problem. There is code below.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface FuncForPath<T> {
    T func(T path);
}

class MethodsForFolder {

    public static void printFilesInFolder(Path path, FuncForPath<Path> funcPath) {
        Stream<Path> paths = null;
        try {
            paths = Files.list(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "The problems have been appeared during reading folder: " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Files list in folder:" + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        paths.forEach(p -> System.out.println(funcPath.func(p).toString())); // I don't know to how to write this code to perform
    }
}

public class TestRefToIntance {

    public static String testWindowsFloder = "C://Logs";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path path = Paths.get(testWindowsFloder);
        // I want that this 2 methods are performed depending on transfered methods
        // reference
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::toAbsolutePath);
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::getFileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it that way but there's normally no need for the `FuncForPath` interface. Just use `Function<Path, Path>`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I have deleted the generic specification in interface description.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

interface FuncForPath { // there is interface without type <T>
    Path func(Path path);
}

class MethodsForFolder {

    public static void printFilesInFolder(Path path, FuncForPath funcPath) {
        Stream<Path> paths = null;
        try {
            paths = Files.list(path);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "The problems have been appeared during reading folder: " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Files list in folder:" + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
        paths.forEach(p -> System.out.println(funcPath.func(p).toString())); // I don't know to how to write this code
                                                                                // to perform
    }
}

public class TestRefToIntance {

    public static String testWindowsFloder = "C://Logs";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Path path = Paths.get(testWindowsFloder);
        // I want that this 2 methods are performed depending on transfered methods
        // reference
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::toAbsolutePath);
        MethodsForFolder.printFilesInFolder(path, Path::getFileName);
    }
}
```